# Return type of a procedure in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am using postgres with postgis and i have a table with geometry data. Now i would like to write a procedure in plpgsql that loop through the rows and store each geometry value in array.

What return typeshall i use to return an array full of geometry values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use `geometry[]` type?

---

**EDIT**

You can use any of the existing PostgreSQL types for arrays, [per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html):

> Arrays of any built-in or user-defined base type, enum type, or
>   composite type can be created.

Comment: You mean 'public.geometry[]'?

Comment: Well, this depends on how PostGIS was installed, but this is what I would expect.